# Typescript: missing lib.d.ts

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, internet-explorer, typescript

I recently wrote something in typescript. I used the Set data structure like this

```
var myset = new Set<string>();
```

I didn't need to include any extra libraries in Typescript and it just works. However, I found out that this only works in IE, as chrome cannot resolve Set data type. Also, when I publish I didn't see anything like lib.d.ts being included in the folder.

How does this work. I am running into some trouble researching as the word "set" has too many meanings and I can't get any useful search result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to the other answer, `Set` is part of the ECMAScript 6 collections API that is not enabled by default in Chrome. You can enable it by checking the "Enable Experimental JavaScript" box in the Chrome `chrome://flags` page, though you're probably better off just not using `Set` yet since very few people will have this enabled. It will be more widespread in browsers in a year or two, most likely.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: Ah! That's it, it was ECMAScript Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `lib.d.ts` file is a Typescript Definition file, and is only needed by the compiler to provide information about external libraries. The file does not contain any browser executable code, only interface and method information for the compiler, therefore it is not needed by the browser, so you will not see it load in the page, or in the published folder contents.

[See this link](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20(.d.ts)%20Files) for information on typescript definitions.

Now as far as your problem with the library, this is most likely a problem with the code itself. What library contains this `Set` object? Is it a third party library, or is it a library written by you?

Comment: Ah! That's it, it was ECMAScript
Thanks!